# String to hexdump

Tags: c++, resources, hex, hexdump

My application reads string from RCData/CONFIG.

I am trying to change the string with C++ application, and I have the source already done:

```
#include <Windows.h>
void main()
{
    char * newData = "wazzup bitches";

    HANDLE hUpdate = BeginUpdateResource("ChangeMyResource.exe", false);
    UpdateResource(hUpdate, MAKEINTRESOURCE(10), "CONFIG", 1, newData, strlen(newData));
    EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, false);
}
```

Before I run the application, it looks like this(Resource Hacker):

[image: -]

And after running the application it looks like this:

[image: -]

How can I change my code like the would look like the original, after the resource modification?

Isn't that basically called "hexdump"? So I should pass the `*newData` to function that makes it hexdump, and then update the resource? or am I wrong?

Someone please point me to the right direction or show me an example.

Been googling this almost for the whole day.

*Sorry for the wazzup b...hes, it's just an example string came on my mind*

Comment: LOL, that's a disturbing way of saying "Hello world" :P

Comment: Yeah, it's well doing alternative :D

Comment: @H2CO3: It's just cultural differences. If you're brought up among dogs, this is perfectly natural... Like iff you grow up among sheep, you might prefer "Hey, ewes".

Comment: @KerrekSB But hey, at least it follows common conventions...

Comment: Anyhow, a solution would be preferred.